# My screen keeps rebuilding when the text field is focused (Flutter)

Tags: flutter, dart, textfield, provider

I am trying to create login and register functionality in my flutter app and I'm using flutter provider for state management. I have wrapped my login button with a consumer widget but it cannot be coursing this problem. Here is a snippet of my login screen.

```
     class LoginState extends State<Login> {
  TextEditingController emailController = TextEditingController();
  TextEditingController passwordController = TextEditingController();

  @override
  void dispose() {
    emailController.text = '';
    passwordController.text = '';
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    double width = MediaQuery.of(context).size.width;
    double height = MediaQuery.of(context).size.height;
    return Scaffold(
        body: SafeArea(
            child: Container(
      width: width,
      height: height,
      padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 20, vertical: 20),
      child: ListView(
        children: [
          const Align(
            alignment: Alignment.topLeft,
            child: Text(
              "Login",
              style: TextStyle(
                  fontFamily: 'Inter',
                  fontSize: 25,
                  fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                  color: AppColors.primaryColor),
            ),
          ),
          SizedBox(height: height * 0.02),
          const Text(
            "Login to your account here ",
            textAlign: TextAlign.left,
            style: AppStyles.bodyTextStyle,
          ),
          SizedBox(height: height * 0.04),
          Image.asset('assets/images/login.png', height: height * 0.4),
          SizedBox(height: height * 0.01),
          CustomInput(
            controller: emailController,
            hintText: 'Email',
            label: '',
            errorMsg: '',
          ),
          const SizedBox(height: 5),
          CustomInput(
            controller: passwordController,
            hintText: 'Password',
            label: '',
            errorMsg: '',
            obscure: true,
          ),
          const SizedBox(height: 20),
          Consumer<AuthenticationProvider2>(builder: (context, auth, child) {
            WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((_) {
              if (auth.resMessage != '') {
                showMessage(context, auth.resMessage);

                //clear the response message
                auth.clear();
              }
            });
            return customButton(
              text: 'Login',
              tap: () async {
                if (emailController.text.isEmpty ||
                    passwordController.text.isEmpty) {
                  showMessage(context, 'All fields are required');
                } else {
                  auth.loginUser(
                    email: emailController.text.trim(),
                    password: passwordController.text.trim(),
                    context: context,
                    callback: (bool loginSuccess) {
                      if (loginSuccess) {
                        showMessage(context, auth.resMessage);
                        PageNavigator(context: context).nextPage(const Home());
                      } else {
                        // Show an error message or handle the unsuccessful login case
                        showMessage(context, auth.resMessage);
                      }
                    },
                  );
                }
              },
              context: context,
            );
          }),
          const SizedBox(height: 25),
          Row(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            children: [
              const Text(
                'New to Ayura? ',
                style: TextStyle(
                  fontSize: 16,
                ),
              ),
              InkWell(
                onTap: () {
                  PageNavigator(context: context).nextPage(const AuthScreen());
                },
                child: const Text(
                  'Sign up',
                  style: TextStyle(
                    fontSize: 16,
                    color: AppColors.primaryColor,
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ],
      ),
```

And here is the code for custom input widget

```
class CustomInput extends StatelessWidget {
  CustomInput({
    Key? key,
    required this.controller,
    required this.hintText,
    required this.label,
    this.width,
    this.height,
    this.obscure,
    this.onInput,
    required this.errorMsg,
  }) : super(key: key);

  final TextEditingController controller;
  final String hintText;
  final String label;
  final double? width;
  final double? height;
  final bool? obscure;
  final void Function()? onInput;
  final String errorMsg;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
      children: [
        Text(
          label,
          style: const TextStyle(
            fontSize: 12,
            fontFamily: 'Inter',
            color: AppColors.primaryColor,
          ),
        ),
        SizedBox(
          width: width, // Set your desired width here
          child: TextField(
            obscureText: obscure ?? false,
            style: const TextStyle(backgroundColor: Colors.white),
            controller: controller,
            onEditingComplete: onInput,
            decoration: AppStyles().inputDecoration(hintText, errorMsg),
          ),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

I tried using onEditingComplete property instead of onchange in the text field but it did not work. And this cannot be a probem with the consumer widget because in my register screen there are other type of inputs like date pickers and radio buttons and those inputs does not rebuild the whole screen everytime I touch them. This is only a problem in my textfields